# Linux Log File doesn't appear

Tags: linux, logging

I have deleted a Log file from a linux server that was occupying 30 GB of memory , but after deleting the memory still occupied and don't know what is the problem , like if the log file was not deleted just transfered somewhere , I have looked over all directories but I don't find it .

What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

The log file wasn't transferred anywhere. Currently it has no names at all (so you won't find it in any directory), but it still exists and occupies space because **it's still in use** – i.e. held open by the service that's writing to it.

As soon as you restart that service, the file will have 0 names *and* 0 open file descriptors, and its space will be marked as free.

Comment: so if I understand ,  you suggest to restart the service using this Log ?